# Distribute In-House UWP application using Microsoft Intune

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app, intune

I am using visual studio 2015 enterprise version to create a UWP application, the client wants the application to be available to their employees via Microsoft Intune.

I have tried to deploy the application to the Microsoft Intune but the client is able to view the application in the apps section but is unable to install the application through company portal.

**Note:** I do not have any sort of developer or enterprise license attached to the application, however I create the APPX bundle with the process mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps). I also select the **NO option** when it asks if I want to upload my app to windows store because I want to upload it on a Intune and not on store.

What would be the possible solution for this what am i missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to deploy a app with Intune it need to be signed with a certificate that is trusted on the device.

From [Add apps with Microsoft Intune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune-classic/deploy-use/add-apps):

> Windows 10 devices do not require a sideloading key to install line of
>   business apps. However, the registry key
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx\AllowAllTrustedApps` must have a value of to 1 to enable sideloading.
>
> If this registry key is not configured, Intune will automatically set
>   this value to 1 the first time you deploy an app to the device. If you
>   have set this value to 0, then Intune cannot automatically change the
>   value, and the deployment of line of business apps will fail.
>
> Universal Windows Platform line of business apps must be signed with a
>   code-signing certificate that is trusted on each device to which the
>   app is deployed. You can use certificates from an in-house PKI
>   infrastructure, or a certificate from a third-party public root
>   certificate installed on the device.
>
> On Windows 10 Mobile devices, you can use a non-Symantec code signing
>   certificate to sign universal .appx apps. For .xap apps, and also
>   .appx packages built for Windows Phone 8.1 that you want to install on
>   Windows 10 Mobile devices, you must use a Symantec code-signing
>   certificate.